# Using selenium webdriver for automation but Not able to click on element

Tags: java, selenium

I am performing automation on my website using selenium webdriver. I am able to login into website but not able to perform click operation on element. 
My code attempts are:

```
WebElement add = BrowserUtilities.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg']"));
add.click();
```

I also tried with javascript executor as below :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) BrowserUtilities.driver;
js.executeScript("argument[0].click()", add);
```

now I am getting exception in console like:

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass launchBrowserTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: argument is not defined
```

Please suggest me if any other solution.

Comment: Replace arguments[0] with argument[0]

Comment: ignore above comment. you missed s after argument. replace argument[0] with arguments[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of javascript and ajax call present you can try this code :

Find Element using webdriver wait as :

```
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50 );           
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@type='Cancel']")));
```

Then perfrom click operation using Actions class as :

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().perfrom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with it.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,9000);   
 WebElement button=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class = 'btn btn-primary btn-lg']")));
    button.click();
```